# Javascript parallax scrolling effect doesn't work in safari

Tags: javascript, safari

This is a script to create a parallax scrolling effect and have the navbar start at the bottom of the screen and stick to the top as you scroll down.  It works perfectly in Firefox.  In Safari, the navbar is not visible and the it does not scroll at all. Any help would be appreciated.

```
var header = document.getElementById("header");
var navBar = document.getElementById("navbar");
var bg = document.getElementById("bg");


var navbarHeight = navBar.offsetHeight;
var headerHeight = header.offsetHeight;

header.style.height = screen.height-navbarHeight;

function initParallax(){
    if(window.pageYOffset > headerHeight){
        navBar.style.position = "fixed";
        navBar.style.top = "0";
    }else{
        navBar.style.position = "absolute";
        navBar.style.top = "0";
    }
    bg.style.top = -(window.pageYOffset/10)+"px";

}

window.addEventListener("scroll", initParallax);
```

Comment: Some CSS code would be appreciated

Comment: Have you done anything to debug? `console.log` the values of variables to see if they match what they should be? Checking the browser console?

Comment: When I open the develper menu in safari, it has moved all my html header tags (<title>Fat Stan's Bar + Pizzeria</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">)
into the body tag.  So it's not reading the css properly.